# Apagar Texto de label com jquery

Tags: jquery, html

Preciso apagar o texto contido dentro da tag label ("Justificativa") com jquery, segue o código:

```js
function add_text() {
  if ($("#tipo").val() == "Falta") {
    $(".b").remove();
    $("#just").remove();
    $("#justificativa").remove();
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="tipo" name="tipo" onchange="add_text()"><option>Falta</option><option>Falta Justificada</option><option>Fardamento Incompleto</option><option selected="">Entrada/Saída Autorizada</option><option>Indisciplína/Outros</option></select><br>
<label>Justificativa: </label><br><textarea required placeholder='Digite a justificativa do aluno...' title='Seja objetivo(a).' rows='5' name='obs' cols='50' id='justificativa'></textarea>
```

Comment: Ela pode possuir ID ?

Comment: Sim @teliz pode sim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adicione um ID ao label

```
<label id="label-justificativa">Justificativa: </label>
```

Adicione ao seu js

```
$("#label-justificativa").remove();
```

--

Penso que pode melhorar seu código:

```js
    function add_text(){     
     if($("#tipo").val()=="Falta"){
             $(".b").remove();
             $("#just").remove();
             $("#opcoes").hide();
        }
        else{
         $("#opcoes").show()
        }
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="tipo" name="tipo" onchange="add_text()">
       <option>Falta</option>
       <option>Falta Justificada</option>
       <option>Fardamento Incompleto</option>
       <option selected="">Entrada/Saída Autorizada</option>
       <option>Indisciplína/Outros</option>
    </select>
    <div id="opcoes">
       <label>Justificativa: </label><br>
       <textarea required placeholder='Digite a justificativa do aluno...'
       title='Seja objetivo(a).' rows='5' name = 'obs' cols='50' 
       id='justificativa'></textarea>
    </div>
```

*Fiz uma modificação que ele somente é ocultado quando valor selecionado é "Falta"*

Assim você remove um bloco inteiro ao invés de ficar procurando as tags que deseja remover, vejo como uma solução mais simples

você também pode usar o [hide()](https://api.jquery.com/hide/) para esconder o html, assim caso queira exibi-lo novamente use o [show()](https://api.jquery.com/show/).